# Online / Offline event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I added two event listeners, one for Online and the other for Offline to my $window. Then I turn off my WiFi. The Offline event listener kicks in and set my variable to false.
Now, if I have an anchor tag with something like this `<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>`, and user clicks on it. This triggers the Online event listener, even though you are still offline. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you provider a fiddler or plunker?

Comment: Please use OfflineJS http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/

Comment: hi, i did what you were doing...but i dont get problem you are having...check here: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/bS97F/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yEU9r/